# ERROR: using '$this' when not in object context

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, this

I have been coding and improving the code **jszobody** provided me that can found on this [LINK](http://3v4l.org/X3i3p) which It makes me to be my refference but it results me to an error `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

PHP:

```
<?php
        function getAllPossiblePermutations($mdArray,  $firstTime=true,  $tempArray=array()) 
        {

            // initialize results array
            if ($firstTime) 
            {
                $this->permutationsResultsArray = array(); 
            }

            // find first sub array and iterate through it
                $thisArray = array_shift($mdArray);

            foreach ($thisArray as $key => $elem) 
            {
                // if this number has already been used  skip this possible permutation
                if (in_array($elem,  $tempArray)) 
                {
                    continue; 
                }
                    $tempArray[] = $elem;

                if (count($mdArray) == 0) 
                {
                    $this->permutationsResultsArray[] = $tempArray;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->getAllPossiblePermutations($mdArray,  false,  $tempArray);
                }
                    array_pop($tempArray);
            }
        } 

    $traits = array
    (
        array('Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Hopeful'),
        array('Outgoing', 'Introverted'),
        array('Tall', 'Short', 'Medium'),
        array('Handsome', 'Plain', 'Ugly')
    );

    print_r(getAllPossiblePermutations($traits));
?>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> Array ( [0] => HappyOutgoingTallHandsome [1](http://3v4l.org/X3i3p) => HappyOutgoingTallPlain [2] => HappyOutgoingTallUgly [3] => HappyOutgoingShortHandsome [4] => HappyOutgoingShortPlain [5] => HappyOutgoingShortUgly [6] => HappyOutgoingMediumHandsome [7] => HappyOutgoingMediumPlain [8] => HappyOutgoingMediumUgly [9] => HappyIntrovertedTallHandsome [10] => HappyIntrovertedTallPlain [11] => HappyIntrovertedTallUgly [12] => HappyIntrovertedShortHandsome [13] => HappyIntrovertedShortPlain [14] => HappyIntrovertedShortUgly [15] => HappyIntrovertedMediumHandsome [16] => HappyIntrovertedMediumPlain [17] => HappyIntrovertedMediumUgly [18] => SadOutgoingTallHandsome [19] => SadOutgoingTallPlain [20] => SadOutgoingTallUgly [21] => SadOutgoingShortHandsome [22] => SadOutgoingShortPlain [23] => SadOutgoingShortUgly [24] => SadOutgoingMediumHandsome [25] => SadOutgoingMediumPlain [26] => SadOutgoingMediumUgly [27] => SadIntrovertedTallHandsome [28] => SadIntrovertedTallPlain [29] => SadIntrovertedTallUgly [30] => SadIntrovertedShortHandsome [31] => SadIntrovertedShortPlain [32] => SadIntrovertedShortUgly [33] => SadIntrovertedMediumHandsome [34] => SadIntrovertedMediumPlain [35] => SadIntrovertedMediumUgly [36] => AngryOutgoingTallHandsome [37] => AngryOutgoingTallPlain [38] => AngryOutgoingTallUgly [39] => AngryOutgoingShortHandsome [40] => AngryOutgoingShortPlain [41] => AngryOutgoingShortUgly [42] => AngryOutgoingMediumHandsome [43] => AngryOutgoingMediumPlain [44] => AngryOutgoingMediumUgly [45] => AngryIntrovertedTallHandsome [46] => AngryIntrovertedTallPlain [47] => AngryIntrovertedTallUgly [48] => AngryIntrovertedShortHandsome [49] => AngryIntrovertedShortPlain [50] => AngryIntrovertedShortUgly [51] => AngryIntrovertedMediumHandsome [52] => AngryIntrovertedMediumPlain [53] => AngryIntrovertedMediumUgly [54] => HopefulOutgoingTallHandsome [55] => HopefulOutgoingTallPlain [56] => HopefulOutgoingTallUgly [57] => HopefulOutgoingShortHandsome [58] => HopefulOutgoingShortPlain [59] => HopefulOutgoingShortUgly [60] => HopefulOutgoingMediumHandsome [61] => HopefulOutgoingMediumPlain [62] => HopefulOutgoingMediumUgly [63] => HopefulIntrovertedTallHandsome [64] => HopefulIntrovertedTallPlain [65] => HopefulIntrovertedTallUgly [66] => HopefulIntrovertedShortHandsome [67] => HopefulIntrovertedShortPlain [68] => HopefulIntrovertedShortUgly [69] => HopefulIntrovertedMediumHandsome [70] => HopefulIntrovertedMediumPlain [71] => HopefulIntrovertedMediumUgly [72] => )

where did I go wrong?

Comment: The link provided does not match the code you pasted.

Comment: You are using `$this` when not in object context.

Comment: You are using $this outside of a class as the error points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of referemces to class variables, like this:

```
$this->permutationsResultsArray = array();
```

And PHP complains since this function is not a method in a class. It will work if you just remove `this->` so you get:

```
$permutationsResultsArray = array();
```

In addition when you are all done you never really return the result.. Like this:

```
return $permutationsResultsArray;
```

There is a problem with it though. You are recusing and you don't create that array except in the first round but your code uses it as if it was defined.

BTW: Your function could be much easier with 3 foreach loops:

```
function getCombinations($traits)
{
    $combinations = array('');
    foreach( $traits as $trait_level ) {
        $new_combinations = array();
        foreach ( $combinations as $comb ) {
            foreach ( $trait_level as $trait ){
                $new_combinations[] = "$comb $trait";
            }
        }
        $combinations = $new_combinations;
    }
    return $combinations;
}
```

Comment: does not giving me an output :(

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @Darline Example of what?

Comment: a code with 3 foreach loops

Comment: @Darline Added. It won't work if `$traits` is empty.

Comment: what you mean won't work if traits where empty?

Comment: it seems i got error If I put 300000 combinations

Comment: @Darline If called with `$traits` empty it will return the array with an empty string instead of an empty array.  What do you mean by 300000? I tried a 7x7 array (823543 combinations) and it worked ok, but be sure to have enough ram because that used about 350M which is much more than the 8M default limit.

Comment: thank you so much for the fastest script done so far and simplier script. :) this would be my referrence thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A function doesn't have a self referential `$this`.  Actually, removing all your `$this->` references and make $tempArray a pass by reference instead of by value, your code should work...

```
function getAllPossiblePermutations($mdArray,  $firstTime=true,  &$tempArray=array())
```

Comment: can you show me a example

Comment: Look at the code I put in there, the &$tempArray has an ampersand in front of it.  That makes it a "by reference" call.  Now remove all references to $this in your function.